# How to Integrate Admob NATIVE Ads in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

How can i integrate Admob Native Ads in my Activity in Android?

and How to use Admob Native Ads?

Please mention the code if possible or any tutorial. I have tried google but could not find any proper tutorial for Integrating Admob Native Ads in Android App.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: @AlexandreMartin I am asking for Admob Native Ads (New Type of Ads by Admob) In the tutorial it only shows how to integrate Banner and Interstitial ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this link it provides the documentation to add Natie Ads: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native

Answer (score 3):

```
NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

---

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="Your ID"
    ads:adSize="320x150">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

Comment: and what is device ID ?